# What are the risks in buying a property from a "Tax Deed" auction?

Tags: united-states, investing, real-estate, risk

Recently, I was approached by a friend of my wife's, and she said that she and her husband were making a lot of money bidding on properties that went up for sale in our area, at auctions like [this one](http://www.co.travis.tx.us/tax_assessor/foreclosure/tax_sales.asp), and then reselling them (without flipping or otherwise improving them).

I believe this is a ["Tax Deed Sale"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax_deed_sale) but I don't know much about it.

My wife and I have some money we've earmarked for making investments, but this sounds like a lot of reward, and I don't understand the risks.  In my experience, risk and reward are directly related, so if there's a lot of money to be made, there's a lot of inherent risk involved.

I found [a couple](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1427795959) [of books](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0836280849) on the subject, but just the titles seem to indicate they're strongly for this type of investment and may not be the unbiased primer I'd want in order to understand them.

What kind of experience/knowledge should I have going into something like this?  What are the risks involved in this type of sale, and how can I learn enough to know whether I'd be making a wise investment?

Comment: Good question agent36!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should read into the local and Federal laws that concern these kinds of sales.
Potential pitfalls that I know of (there are probably much more):

1. In many states, these "auctions" are rather random, and you can't
   chose the property you buy.
2. Owners may repay the taxes, in which cases (depending on the local laws) you may have to give up the property back to the owner.
3. You'll have to foreclose on the property to get full ownership on it.
4. There may be time limitations as to what and when you can do (for example, I know that in some states you have to wait for a certain period of time before you're allowed to foreclose, several years).

Auctions in general mean:

1. Many times you cannot inspect the property prior to purchase.
2. You have to pay very quickly (and to decide very quickly).
3. You will probably have to invest significantly in rehab and repairs before reselling.
4. You might not get a title insurance

Comment: What is it that I'm actually purchasing then?  If they've got, say, an unpaid mortgage, does that mean the bank also has some rights to the property as well?

Comment: You're purchasing the debt. Yes, if there's a delinquent mortgage, it might be that you'll have to fight the bank's claims.

Comment: @littleadv, why would you bid on anything you cannot inspect prior to purchase? Also, in your point 2 above, doesn't the previous owner only have a certain period of time in which they can purchase back the property and don't they have to pay back the bid price plus a penalty to the new owner?

Comment: @Victor - why? Because its cheap. Its a gamble. Yes, the time the previous owner can buy it back is limited, and the owner generally has to reimburse the bid. But there would be no gain, and wasted value of money, so that's a risk. The time can be anywhere between days and years. In the case of the OP, in Texas, its several months.

Comment: @littleadv, well from the link the OP provided, in Texas it is a 2 year period for a homestead with a 25% penalty above the purchase price which goes up to a 50% penalty after the first year. So a 25% profit in less than a year seems a good risk to me.

Comment: @Victor - I don't know the details, really, that's what lawyers are for. The OP asked for the risks, and that's what I listed. If it worth the potential chance of getting 25% return? Maybe. Maybe not. Who promises that the delinquent taxpayer will pay the debt? Who promises that the bank won't foreclose first? Who promises that he can sell the foreclosed property for more than he invested in the purchase, legalities and repairs? No-one. But the expenses are pretty steep, and the 25% penalty on the taxpayer paying him off is the *best* scenario, not the *usual*.

Comment: @littleadv, I understand there is risks, especially if you say you cannot inspect before hand, which i think is stupid. But you have stated that the original owner buying back is a risk as they pay no compensation or penalty. I am from Australia and know nothing about these rules and laws, but just reading the link provided by the OP has provided information contradicting one of the main risks you pointed out. So how well researched and correct are your other points?

Comment: @Victor The OP only provided a link to a specific county in a specific state. There are 50 states in the US, each comprised of numerous counties. The variance of laws and regulations is enormous.

Comment: @Victor, By the way, my point #1 may be irrelevant for the OP specifically as well. But when I researched for myself - I was looking at NV, .AZ and CA, where the laws are completely different.

Comment: Yes the OP provided a link to a specific county for which the OP is from, so the information in it is relavent to the OP.

Comment: But we want the answers to be relevant to all the readers, not just the OP. The OP will research what are the risks that apply to him, and in what manner, that's his job as an investor. He didn't come here for a legal advice. But if some risks don't apply to the OP - they apply to someone else who has exactly the same question, but for a different county. They'll need to do their research as well. The "global" list doesn't change, the results of that "due diligence" research do.

Comment: @littleadv, so that means I could be giving an answer based on Australian Tax Law to someone asking a question from the USA or the UK or some other country. I thought that was the whole point in having country and/or region tabs, so the answer could be specific to the person asking the question. Sorry but your answer and explanations don't make any sense.

Comment: @Victor, yes, you could. And you in fact do, occasionally. I don't know how many jurisdictions are there in Australia, but in the US its about 10,000. You do no expect people to get a precise answer for every single county they're asking about here, do you?

Comment: @littleadv, I usually do that for 2 reasons. 1st reason, I don't know where the person asking the question is from (no country/region tag or indication in the question where they are from). 2nd reason, to give a comparions of the differences or similarities between different countries. And when I do I always specify where I am from and where my answer is specific to.